# Javascript error: Uncaught RangeError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': Out of memory at ImageData creation

Tags: javascript, html, out-of-memory

I was writing a simple web app for drawing pictures. I was writing code for a flood fill tool. The tool works for filling small spaces but for big spaces it will fill partway and just stop. I checked the console and it was spammed with errors of

```
Uncaught RangeError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': Out of memory at ImageData creation
```

```js
function move(e, s, c){
  if(!e.value)
  e.style.right = s + "px";
  else 
  e.style.right = c + "px";
 e.value = !e.value;
}

function fixGradient(){
 var color1 = 238;
 var color2 = 221;
 var y = 42;
 var height = 50;
 
 var slope = (color1 - color2) / (0 - height);
 var intercept = color1 - ((slope) * y);
 var screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
 var bottomColor = Math.round(slope * screenHeight + intercept);
 var color = "rgb(" + bottomColor + ", " + bottomColor + ", " + bottomColor + ")";
 document.getElementById("panel").style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(#FCFCFC, " + color + ")";
 
}
var colorValue = "#000000";
function setColor(color){
 ctx.fillStyle = color;
 ctx.strokeStyle = color;
 colorValue = color.toUpperCase();
}
var con = 1 / Math.sqrt(2);
var mouseDown = false;
var click = false;
var size = 2;
var position = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var ctx;
var tool = 0;
var canvas;
var busy = false;
function set(t){
 tool = Number(t);
}
function getFile(){
 document.getElementById("bgchooser").click();
}
function setBG(e){
 /*
 var f = new FileReader();
 f.readAsDataURL( el("f").files[0] );
 f.onload = function(e){
  var b64 = e.target.result;
  el("loc").value = b64;
  change();
 }
 */
 var file = e.files[0];
 var reader = new FileReader(file);
 reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 reader.onload = function(r){
  var b64 = r.target.result;
  canvas.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + b64 + "')";
 }
}
window.onload = function(){
 
 canvas = document.getElementById("c");
 canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
  mouseDown = true;
  position[6] = position[0];
  position[7] = position[1];
 });
 window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
  mouseDown = false;
 });
 window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if(keyCode == 82){
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
 });
 canvas.addEventListener("click", function(){
  click = true;
 });
 window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
  position[4] = position[2];
  position[5] = position[3];
  position[2] = position[0];
  position[3] = position[1];
  position[0] = e.clientX;
  position[1] = e.clientY;
 });
 canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
 canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
 
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var scale = [1, 1];
 setInterval(function(){
  fixGradient();
  size = Number(document.getElementById("size").value) * con;
  document.getElementById("display").style.height = size + "px";
  document.getElementById("liveDisplay").innerHTML = size + "px";
  ctx.lineWidth = size;
  scale[0] = canvas.width / window.innerWidth;
  scale[1] = canvas.height / window.innerHeight;
  if(tool==0){
   canvas.style.cursor = "url(eyedrop.cur), crosshair";
   if(mouseDown){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(position[4] * scale[0], position[5] * scale[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(position[2] * scale[0], position[3] * scale[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(position[0] * scale[0], position[1] * scale[1]);
    ctx.stroke();
    
    //fill gaps
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(position[0] * scale[0], position[1] * scale[1], size / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.fill();
   } else {
    //if(click&&position[6]==position[0]&&position[7]==position[1]) ctx.fillRect(position[0] * scale[0] - (size / 2), position[1] * scale[1] - (size / 2), size, size);
    position[2] = position[0];
    position[3] = position[1];
    position[4] = position[0];
    position[5] = position[1];
    click = false;
   }
  } else if(tool==1){
   if(mouseDown){
    ctx.clearRect(position[0] * scale[0] - size / 2, position[1] * scale[1] - size / 2, size, size);
   }
  } else if(tool==2){
   var x = position[0];
   var y = position[1];
   var index = x * 4 + y * canvas.width * 4;
   var imgdata = canvas.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   var data = imgdata.data;
   
  } else if(tool==3){
   //paint bucket may be taken out or not left in
   var x = position[0];
   var y = position[1];
   var idata;
   try{
    idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
   } catch(e){
    setTimeout(100);
    idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
   }
   var idataindex = 4 * (x + y * canvas.width)
   if(mouseDown){
    flood(canvas, ctx, x, y, [idata[idataindex], idata[idataindex + 1], idata[idataindex + 2], idata[idataindex + 3]], [255, 0, 0, 255]);
    mouseDown = false;
   }
  }
 }, 0);
}

function getPixel(data, x, y, width){
 return [data[4 * (y * width + x)], data[4 * (y * width + x) + 1], data[4 * (y * width + x) + 2], data[4 * (y * width + x) + 3]];
}

function scan(x, y, o, n, c, t){
 console.log("Scanning: (" + x + ", " + y + "), old=new: " + (o==n) + ", old: " + o + ", new: " + n);
 if(o != n){
  var data = t.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height).data;
  if(y!=0){
   var top = getPixel(data, x, y - 1, c.width);
   if(top[0] == o[0] && top[1] == o[1] && top[2] == o[2] && top[3] == o[3]){
    t.fillRect(x, y - 1, 1, 1);
    scan(x, y - 1, o, n, c, t);
   }
  }
  if(x!=c.width){
   var right = getPixel(data, x + 1, y, c.width);
   if(right[0] == o[0] && right[1] == o[1] && right[2] == o[2] && right[3] == o[3]){
    t.fillRect(x + 1, y, 1, 1);
    scan(x + 1, y, o, n, c, t);
   }
  }
  if(x!=0){
   var left = getPixel(data, x - 1, y, c.width);
   if(left[0] == o[0] && left[1] == o[1] && left[2] == o[2] && left[3] == o[3]){
    t.fillRect(x - 1, y, 1, 1);
    scan(x - 1, y, o, n, c, t);
   }
  }
  if(y!=c.height){
   var bottom = getPixel(data, x, y + 1, c.width);
   if(bottom[0] == o[0] && bottom[1] == o[1] && bottom[2] == o[2] && bottom[3] == o[3]){
    t.fillRect(x, y + 1, 1, 1);
    scan(x, y + 1, o, n, c, t);
   }
  }
 }
}

function flood(c, cctx, x, y, oldColor, newColor){
 if(!busy){
  busy = true;
  var oldFill = ctx.fillStyle;
  //ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + newColor[0] + ", " + newColor[1] + ", " + newColor[2] + ")";
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
  scan(x, y, oldColor, newColor, c, ctx);
  busy = false;
 }
}
```

```css
body{
 margin: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.canvas{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 background: white;
 cursor: url(aero_pen.cur), crosshair;
}
.button{
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
 border: 1px solid #808080;
 border-right: medium none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background-image: linear-gradient(#EEEEEE, #DDDDDD);
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 40px;
 right: 0px;
 transition: right 0.2s;
 z-index: 11;
}
.panel{
 border-left: 1px solid #808080;
 width: 251px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 z-index: 10;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right: -251px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(#FCFCFC, #262626);
 height: 100%;
 transition: right 0.2s;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 overflow: auto;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}
label{
 font-family: Tahoma;
}
input[type=color], input[type=range], input[type=button]{
 width: calc(100% - 6px);
}
.display{
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: black;
 border-radius: 4px;
}
select{
 width: 100%;
 padding: 4px;
 font-weight: bold;
 appearance: button;
 border: 1px inset #808080;
}
option:hover{
 background-color: #808080;
 color: white;
}
.hidden{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Art Program</title>
    </head>
    <body>
  <canvas id="c" class="canvas"></canvas>
  <div class="expand button" onclick="move(this, 250, 0); move(document.getElementById('panel'), 0, -251);" value="false"></div>
  <div class="panel" value="false" id="panel">
   <div>
    <label>Color: </label>
    <br/>
    <input type="color" value="black" onchange="setColor(this.value);"/>
   </div>
   <hr/>
   <div>
    <label>Tool: </label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="tool" value="0" checked="true" onclick="set(this.value);"/>
    <label>Pencil</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="tool" value="1" onclick="set(this.value);"/>
    <label>Eraser</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="tool" value="2" onclick="set(this.value);"/>
    <label>Eyedropper</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="tool" value="3" onclick="set(this.value);"/>
    <label>Flood Fill</label>
   </div>
   <hr/>
   <div>
    <label>Background: </label>
    <br/>
    <input type="file" class="hidden" id="bgchooser" onchange="setBG(this);"/>
    <input type="button" value="Choose Background" onclick="getFile();"/>
   </div>
   <hr/>
   <div>
    <label>Language: </label>
    <br/>
    <select>
     <option>বাঙালি</option>
     <option>English (UK)</option>
     <option>English (US)</option>
     <option>Español</option>
     <option>فُصْحَى</option>
     <option>汉语</option>
     <option>漢語</option>
     <option>हिन्दी</option>
     <option>português</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <hr/>
   <div>
    <label>Size: </label>
    <br/>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="2" id="size"/>
    <br/>
    <label id="liveDisplay">2</label>
    <div class="display" id="display"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the code snippet, but I thought it would be best to put it in all its entirety. Is there a way to prevent these RangeErrors (not SecurityErrors)?
[zoomed up slowed down visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsIpg.gif)

Comment: Never use a `setInterval(f,0)`, best way to kill a browser. Instead use debounced event handlers (thanks to a requestAnimationFrame call. Don't call `getImageData` that much. Do it once, then store it in a variable and always loop through the same imageData. And since memory is a problem, no need to convert your file as a dataURL, just convert it to a blobURI ( `URL.createObjectURL(yourfile)`).

Comment: I changed those things and it runs smoother now. Currently though now I'm running into problems with the Call Stack. I've tried using setTimeout to reset it but to no avail.